# Black screen after wake up

Tags: release-loki, suspend

I know this is a spread out problem out there. 3 days ago i installed el os (loki) on my computer and i noticed that after suspension, when i had a wake up the screen remained black. no pointer, anything, moreover the screen power button shows me a red light (like there's no signal). I've looked for out there and some of the solutions i found don't work (typing password, ctrl alt f1, f7 or something like that).
Any advice?

Comment: Are you running TLP? Could be the problem. TLP causes all kinds of wake up issues.

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm having this on at least 25% of my sleep/wakeup cycles.

Comment: I hadn't time to fix the problem (and i had some others), so i decided to remove the os and return to windows :)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the kernel works for me. I guess it works if having newer cpu is your problem.